# How to add dropdown YearID in current model section

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

**What I need**

I need to add drop down and LabelFor  YearID and add  from model Year to
current model section with Formate bootstrap as (Replace departID WITH YearID).

I work in MVC 5 visual studio 2015  and i need to get drop down list from another model .

**Current model name is Section:**

```
namespace UniversityData.Models  
{  

   [Table("Section")]  
    public partial class Section  
    {  
        public Section()  
        {  

        }  
         [Key]
        public int SecID { get; set; }  

        [Required]  
        [StringLength(50)]  
        public string SecName{ get; set; }  

        [ForeignKey("Department")]  
        [DisplayName("DepartmentName")]  
        public int departID { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

My code to drop down departID inside my current model section  with bootstrapis:

```
<div class="form-group">  
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.departID, "DepartmentName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })  
          <div class="col-md-10">  
              @Html.DropDownList("departID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })  
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.departID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
          </div>  
      </div>
```

Another model Year I want to generate dropdown to it

```
 [Table("Year")]  
    public partial class Year  
    {  
        public Year()  
        {  
         this.department = new HashSet<Department>();  

        }  
        [Key]  
        public int YearID { get; set; }  
        [Required]  
        [StringLength(50)]  

        public string YearName { get; set; }  

    }  
}
```

**what i try as following :**

```
  <div class="form-group">
```

// how to add labelfor replace of text

```
           YearName:
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("YearID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>
```

**I get error :**

> {"DataBinding: 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Department_3D49A8148DA2B6C2F8801CE72951BF7FDBF82503B3A52665397F8B7058E3F8A8' does not contain a property with the name 'YearName'."}

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I solved my problem

**The problem found in action :**

```
  ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(db.years.ToList(), "YearID", "YearName");
```

**before it found as db.departments.ToList() so that error come after i change departments to years problem solved because drop down for years not department .**

And in view i do as following :

```
 <div class="form-group">

            @Html.Label("YearName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("YearID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>
```